# get the next date based on frequency set using google sheet formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to display the upcomind date based on the start date and frequency set.

[image]
I have tried with

```
=TODAY() + MOD(TODAY() - C2, F2)
```

[Here is the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LBpxS3UxAQMUzzvSub71oPdt92j-bZ5KRBWFqJik3Ng/edit#gid=0)

Comment: What is the frequency mean in your case?

Comment: What is the expected output? will the output be a **single** date ? or a **sequence** of dates based on the frequency? In any case, an example with the expected output would help the people here provide you with a solution.

Comment: frequency means the repetition again and again after n number of days.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

The upcoming date is given by:

```
=((((((C2-DATE(1970,1,1))*86400)+(((D2-DATE(1970,1,1))*86400)-((C2-DATE(1970,1,1))*86400))/H2)/60)/60)/24)+DATE(1970,1,1)
```

This is equivalent to:

```
                (end date) - (start date)
(start date) + ___________________________
                       (frequency)
```

Where each date is converted to a unix timestamp for calculation and converted back to date format for display.

Remember that `frequency` will have to be decremented when each upcoming date passes in order to update the formula to the new upcoming date.

#### References:

- [DATE - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092969?hl=en)
- [Unix Time - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

Answer (score 0):

Could try:

```
G2 + F$2-MOD(G2  - C$2, F$2)
```

where G2 is today's date

[image]

Comment: What is G2 here?

Comment: G2 represents today's date (easier to test than actually using Today())